# Seem to get segfaults from Copy Constructor?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm writing some C++ code for a simple "Node" class.  This is basically a class used to manage a linear linked list.  I normally perform this with a struct but I'm trying get a better handle of OOP and classes.  What I've got thus far for the Node class is (note: the String class is my version (trimmed down) of a typical "string" class, it implements a copy constructor, assignment overload, destructor, etc. In testing it has worked great and seems completely self contained):

```
class Node {
public:

    //Constructor
    //-----------

    Node() : next_(0) {} //inline (String constructor called)

    //Destructor
    //----------

    ~Node(); 

    //Copy Constructor
    //----------------

    Node(const Node &);    

    //Operator Overload: =
    //---------------------
    //In conjunction with copy constructor.  Protects Class.

    Node & operator=(const Node &);   

private:

    String relatedEntry_;
    Node * next_;
};
```

Creating one instance works fine (ie. `Node node;`) but when I create an instance that calls the Copy Constructor I end up with segfaults at the very end of my program, as it's cleaning up.  The difference between using a struct for a linked list vs a class plays tricks with me a little and I think I'm missing something key here.  Here is the implementation for the Default Constructor, Copy Constructor, and Overloaded Assignment Operator:

```
//Constructor inlined

//Destructor
Node::~Node()
{
    Node * curr = next_;
    while (curr) //cycle through LL and delete nodes
    {
        Node * temp = curr; //hold onto current
        curr = curr->next_; //increment one
        delete temp; //delete former current
    }
}


//Copy Constructor
Node::Node(const Node & cp)
{
    std::cout << "in CopyCon" << std::endl;
    relatedEntry_ = cp.relatedEntry_; //calls String class copy constructor/assignment overload
    Node * curr = cp.next_; //for clarity, for traversal
    while (curr) //copies related entry structure
    {
        Node * oldNext = next_;
        next_ = new Node;
        next_->next_ = oldNext; //'next' field (assign prior)
        next_->relatedEntry_ = curr->relatedEntry_; //String class copy
        curr = curr->next_; //increment
    }
}


//OO:  =
Node & Node::operator=(const Node & cp)
{
    std::cout << "in OO: =" << std::endl;
    if (this == &cp)
        return *this; //self assignment
    delete next_; //delete LL
    relatedEntry_ = cp.relatedEntry_; //String Class Assignment Overload
    Node * curr = cp.next_; //for clarity, for traversal
    while (curr)
    {
        Node * oldNext = next_; //hold onto old
        next_ = new Node; 
        next_->next_ = oldNext; //set next to old
        next_->relatedEntry_ = curr->relatedEntry_; //set this string to cp string
        curr = curr->next_; //increment
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Note that using the Overloaded Assignment Function seems to work fine (no segfaults) even though it's virtually the same code...  I'm assuming it has to do with the fact that both objects are already initialized *before* the assignment takes place?

```
//This seems to work ok
Node node1;
Node node2;
node2 = node1;
```

I've been at this bug for a couple of hours and I have got to get some rest.  I'd really appreciate any insight into this.  Thanks.

Comment: The first thing you should do when getting a crash, segmentation fault or any other, is to run your program in a debugger. Not only will it help you find the location of the crash, but also let you examine variables to help you figure out the cause.

Comment: What should next_ be on the line `Node * oldNext = next_; //hold onto old`?

Comment: I disagree the reark "_it's virtually the same code_". Your code of the operator= is not the same code as the implicit one: you make a deep copy of the whole list, whereas the default assignment operator just makes a shallow copy of the object (copy of the string and the pointer _next.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg of the two hours I spent on debugging this last night almost all of it was in GDB and/or DDD.

Comment: @Bentoy13 Is it really?  I am copying the node into a "new node" and I'm copying the String using the String class copy constructor/assignment overload (which should create a new object).  Am I missing something?

Comment: @MCP I may be wrong, but for me the default copy of any object is the copy of the content itself and no more, i.e. not deferencing any pointer in the list of object members. What you do, especially the while-loop, seems to me a deep copy of the complete list, not only the current Node. Or do I completely misunderstand this part of the code ?

Comment: I'm trying to make a deep copy in both cases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the copy constructor loop, you have this line:

```
Node * oldNext = next_;
```

However, in the first round in the loop the value of `next_` can by, well, anything and most likely not `NULL`. This means that the last node will a have a non-null pointer.

Initialize it to `NULL` before the loop and it should work.

Comment: In the Default Constructor for the Node class I initialize next_ to 0.  This should take care of that, no?

Comment: @MCP No, since the default construct is not called, only the copy constructor.

Comment: Wow. I've tried it and it works.  Huge thanks.  I must be misunderstanding how the copy constructor works.  Can you explain this more? I thought that next_ would originally be initialized to '0' since that is what the regular constructor would have done for an object.  Is it that the copy constructor creates a new object without ever calling the regular constructor?  So when I'm doing something like:  "Node node1; //regular"  then  "Node node2 = node1; //copy"  I'm creating node2 with the copy constructor and I've got to take care of all initialization?  No regular constructor?  Thanks!

Comment: @MCP That's right, the compiler invokes only one constructor. It's either a "normal" constructor, or a copy constructor, or in the case of C++11 a move constructor.

Comment: @MCP Talking about C++11, if your compiler supports it you can call another constructor in a constructors initializer list, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Object_construction_improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You have the concepts of a List and a Node mixed up. You should write a List class which manages a sequence of Nodes. Your Node destructor is more or less how your List destructor should look, Node itself doesn't need a destructor.

What is specifically going wrong is that your Node destructor recursively calls itself when you write `delete temp;` this deletes the rest of the sequence of nodes but then your Node destructor loops around and tries to delete them again.

Comment: This is what I was feeling yesterday...  What doesn't make sense though is how the List class would manage the nodes.  How would it contain the nodes?  A struct inside the class?  Thanks for any further advice you can provide.

Comment: Simplest is a pointer to the first node. `class List { public: ... private: Node* head; }`